# Eureka Server without Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat, microservices, netflix-eureka

I am looking to setup a eureka server without spring. I downloaded the following war file:

http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22eureka-server%22

I am deploying the war on a local Tomcat v8.5. During startup i get the following log (pastebin due to size):

https://pastebin.com/z4c26D3E

The main errors are "Request execution error" --> "Read timed out" and "Cannot execute request on any known server". The dashboard at http://localhost:8080/eureka/ starts properly, but lists:

registered-replicas        http://localhost:8080/eureka/v2/

available-replicas

unavailable-replicas        http://localhost:8080/eureka/v2/

I am using the default configuration files and only changed the

`eureka.waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty=0`

`eureka.numberRegistrySyncRetries=0`

values to decrease the startup time. Here are the .properties files i am currently using:

https://pastebin.com/AUKeZRmQ

https://pastebin.com/Y18rYRgp

Where did i go wrong? I feel like this should be a simple configuration mistake on my part.

Comment: Is the error on the server side or the client side?

Comment: I only run the server currently, but as far as I understand it every eureka server is also a eureka client. So I can't really say where the problem lies

Comment: You can disable auto registration of eureka server as a client, if you want with `eureka.registration.enabled`, i think.

Comment: Also is that error repeating after an interval or is it a one time error?

Comment: It does repeat periodically